# Spring form:input not null

Tags: spring, forms

I have a form with a form:input which looks like a textbox. My issue is that this input has a deafult value of "0" and I cant seem to replace it with null.

The field is currently set to value = "". When value is changed to something else then the field DOES hold the new value, as long as its not null or "". I tried removing value, no effect. I tried using default, no effect.

I have pulled what I believe to be the line at issue over to the left so it stands out more. Seems I cant bold code lines.

```
    <tbody>
        <c:if test="${not empty drillobject.newList}">
            <c:forEach var="newREC" items="${drillobject.newRecList}" varStatus="vs">
                <tr>
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${newRec.filenumber==0}">
                            <td>
    <form:input id="fileNumber${vs.index}" path="newRecList[${vs.index}].filenumber" cssClass="form-control" value=""  />
                            </td>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            <td style="text-align: center">
                                <a href="Record?FileNumber=${newRec.filenumber}" target="blank_"><c:out value="${newRec.filenumber}" /></a>
                            </td>
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:if>
    </tbody>
```

Here is the controller.

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "/thispage", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public String thispage(HttpServletRequest request, Model model)
    {
        NewRecInfo RecList = new NewRecInfo();
        RecList.setNewRecList(myService.getRecList());
        model.addAttribute("drillobject",  RecList);

        return "thispage";
    }
```

Here is the java class with everything for filenumber.

```java
    public class NewRecRow  {
        private String filenumber;
        public String getfilenumber()
        {
            return filenumber;
        }
        public void setfilenumber(String newfile)
        {
            filenumber=newfile;
        }
    }
```

Things that I have tried (shorted for convince)

```java
    <form:input value=""  />
    <form:input value=" "  />
    <form:input   />
    <form:input value="" default="" />
    <form:input value="" default="asdf" />
    <form:input value="${newRec.filenumber}"  />
```

Comment: What does drillobject.newRecList return? Please post the class too. (should include the java type of filenumber)

Comment: @ialam I have added the requested information

Comment: have you tried this?

<form:input id="fileNumber${vs.index}" path="newRecList[${vs.index}].filenumber" cssClass="form-control" **value="${newREC.filenumber}"**  />

Comment: @ialam I had not, but I have now, and no change. Field still displays a "0" in it

Comment: I will check this in my machine and let you know.

Comment: @ialam I found the issue, it was with the rowmapper, thank you for for your time

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, it was with the rowmapper in the DAO. So what happened was the value gets read first as an Integer, which assigns the null value to 0 since Integers cant be null if they are initiated, and when cast to string the 0 value gets transferred.

```java
    class myMapper implements RowMapper<NewRecRow> {
        public NewRecRow mapRow(ResultSet rs, int arg1) throws SQLException 
        { 
            NewRecRow model = new NewRecRow();

            //replace this
            //model.setfilenumber(Integer.toString(rs.getInt("FILE_NUMBER")));

            //with this
            int mytemp = rs.getInt("FILE_NUMBER");
            boolean iszero = (mytemp==0);
            model.setfilenumber((iszero?"":Integer.toString(mytemp)));

            return model;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good to hear this. Thanks for sharing it.